# Targeting a specific Chrome process?

Tags: c#, .net, process, system.diagnostics

When I open the Chrome's Task Manager, I can see something like this?

[image]

Now, programatically, is it somehow possible to target the Chrome instance that is being used to run the Flash Plug-In? Maybe using System.Diagnostics.Process class or native API calls?

Comment: Hmm, Google's sense of humor looks just as grating in Italian.

Comment: Hahah yes absolutely. Even worse in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this with native api calls. My solution worked perfectly on my machine. Here is what I did:

First, get [Microsoft Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). Using this tool, I was able to get the flash plugin dll's name that chrome uses which is called **pepflashplayer.dll** in my case.

Next, a little search on Bing got me this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10531/Find-and-kill-a-process-which-uses-the-specified-l). It's C code so I converted to C# and after some coding I was able to retrieve the correct Chrome process ID that uses flash plug-in.

I have uploaded my solution to SkyDrive for you to check [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=FE433F5559E406BE!1071&authkey=!AJiAqqJj49ZUIsE). Note that I am not closing any handles in my sample so you'll have to add that for a real project.

There might be better solutions out there but this one should work. Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent answer! Excellent! Do you know what happens in this case if you have more than one tab displaying a flash object? Will you still find only one instance?

Comment: Using Process Explorer, I can see that Chrome launches only one process with the flash plugin regardless of how many tabs displaying flash objects. So yea, you will find only one instance and killing that instance will stop all flash objects in all tabs.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to improve the portability of your implementation for a 64x environment also?

Comment: This works fine on 64 bit machines and can enumerate 64 bit instances on the system. Ignore the "32" part of the name. Its an old API I guess.